# Calculate percentage in SQL

Tags: sql

I've a table named `ExamResult` which has following columns

```
studentId, Subject, Standard, Marks
```

and i've following values in my table

for studentId=1

```
1,maths,9,78
1,english,9,80
1,history,9,67
1,geography,9,90
```

for studentId=2

```
2,maths,9,68
2,english,9,83
2,history,9,70
2,geography,9,69
```

similar entries till studentId 30

now I want to calculate the percentage of each student and want to select data from the table with the following columns

```
studentName(from student table),Standard,Percentage(with highest percentage on top)
```

**Eg:**

```
Amit,9,78%
Sam,9,77%
```

now the problem is how to calculate this percentage in SQL,

```
select stu.name,exam.standard,(what to do here) as Percentage 
from Student stu 
inner join ExamResult exam
on stu.Id=exam.studentId;
```

Please help me

Comment: instead of downvoting, it would be good if you could help me or let me know where i'm doing wrong

Comment: Look up aggregate functions and `group by`. Also, when posting sql questions you should include the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: What's your definition of percentage, how to calculate it?

Comment: sum of total marks obtained by a student by 400 and then multiply by 100 to calculate %

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT stu.name, exam.standard, AVG(stu.marks) as 'Percentage'
FROM Student stu 
INNER JOIN ExamResult exam
    ON stu.Id=exam.studentId;
GROUP BY stu.name, exam.standard
```

NOTE: This is biased towards Microsoft SQL Server's flavor of SQL.  You didn't specify which version you were using.  Hopefully you can get it working from here.

Comment: thank you for the answer, can't upvote you as don't have enough reputation.

Comment: can you plzz tell me one more thing how can i add % sign in my record?

Comment: I would recommend doing it in code, but if you must do it in SQL:

Comment: CAST(AVG(stu.marks) AS VARCHAR) + '%' AS 'Percentage'

Answer (score 1):

Have you worked with group-by clause?

```
select stu.name,exam.standard, **average(marks) as Percentage** 
from Student stu 
inner join ExamResult exam
on stu.Id=exam.studentId
**group by stendent_id
order by Percentage  desc**
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the AVERAGE function to average the scores:

```
select stu.name,exam.standard,AVERAGE(marks) + '%'  as Percentage 
from Student stu 
inner join ExamResult exam
on stu.Id=exam.studentId
group by stu.name, exam.standard;
```

The group by will treat each student/exam pair as a seperate row, so that your results will have one row per student/exam combo and will average the marks for each exam that is part of that student exam combo.

Comment: thank you for the answer and explanation, it cleared lot of things. can't upvote you as don't have enough reputation.

Comment: can you plzz tell me one more thing how can i add % sign in my record?

Comment: @PrachiJain That is just concatenation.  In most db vendors that will be a +.  In Oracle it is ||.  Ex: AVERAGE(marks) + '%' will add a % after your average.  Let me know what db platform you are using if that doesn't work.

Comment: Thank u for the answer, can't mark it as an answer but yeah a +1 from my side for helping me out. :)